# Javascript- Fill Out a Form

Tags: javascript, form, library

I am working on a fairly complex system right now, and the task I am currently stuck on is the creation of a document using JavaScript.  I have a form library created with Infopath, and I would like to be able to create a semi-blank form from my JavaScript code.  I don't need to do much with it- essentially just copy the template and alter some metadata.  Does anyone know how to do this?  I have been searching online for information, but I haven't come up with much.

Answer (score 2):

I wouldn't recommend trying to manipulate the SharePoint InfoPath viewer, I would insert any code needed directly into the InfoPath form template before publishing to SharePoint. From there you can setup your pre-populate conditions among other things. Beware however, web enabled InfoPath forms cannot do everything that regular InfoPath forms can do. It all depends on what exactly you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: Btw - The reason I wouldn't recommend manipulating the InfoPath using java-script this way is because I believe that if your form changes or gets updated, keeping your code and your form working together will get messy over time.

Comment: For Example `<input type="text" onfocus="return (TextBox.OnFocus(this, event));" onblur="return (TextBox.OnBlur(this, event));" oninput="return (TextBox.OnInput(this, event));" id="ctl00_ctl29_g_6f49e1c8_c19d_4d31_91a8_1a70eff54cc9_FormControl0_V1_I1_S3_I1_T3" scriptclass="TextBox" class="am_RhRPkLWFeQkVhSbL_0 bk_RhRPkLWFeQkVhSbL_0 fh_RhRPkLWFeQkVhSbL_0" wrapped="true" aria-invalid="true" "="" direction="ltr" viewdatanode="8" formid="ctl00_ctl29_g_6f49e1c8_c19d_4d31_91a8_1a70eff54cc9_FormControl0" originalid="V1_I1_S3_I1_T3" tabindex="0" title="" value="" style="position: relative;"` -- etc

Comment: I'm actually not trying to work with the InfoPath viewer- I am working on a scheduling system.  When a manager schedules a user, it should create a travel request form for them, which they will then need to fill out.  I am simply trying to create a blank form automatically from my JS code.

Comment: Okay, What I would do is create a page with an Info-path form web part, we can call it "Page B". This will give you a blank form for the travel request. 

From the page where the manager schedules a user, "Page A", you have the JavaScript redirect them to "Page B". Since you want it to be "semi-blank" you will have to pass the data from "Page A" via some global variables or through the query string.

I still see the same problem however, your InfoPath <input> tags get auto id's, this will become problematic in the future.

Comment: I would use, instead of javascript to pass the value, code in the InfoPath form to read from the query string. Like the following example:
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/infopath/archive/2010/06/03/how-to-pass-querystring-data-into-an-infopath-form.aspx

Comment: Actually, I don't want the manager to ever interact with the form.  The idea is that they will use a point-and-click interface to schedule a user, which will automatically create the form, and the manager will only see the form once the employee has completed it and submitted it for approval.

Comment: Okay this is probably even easier then, the info-path files are simple XML files stored in the document library that when clicked the form's template is opened and populated with the raw XML data (One template many XML files) . On the page that the manager is interfacing with to schedule the user, I am assuming it is a web form, you could write some code that "on submit" parses the input from the manager to an XML file that matches the XML layout of your info-path form and writes it to the document library. Also just an FYI, SharePoint workflows still key off of this as a new item being added.

Comment: Yes, but the problem is that I need a way to submit this data.  Also, I was thinking I had read somewhere that there was an interface designed for this sort of thing (similar to the list interface) that would allow me to create the documents without directly modifying the XML.

Comment: If you are looking for an out of the box solution without writing any code, you could also try to create a view of your infopath form for the data that the manager will fill out.

http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/infopath-help/introduction-to-views-HA010156628.aspx

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/10165/discussion-between-bob-and-crash)

Answer (score 0):

It could be done also in workflow initiation form, but be carufull. By modifications to IniWrkflIP.aspx page you make changes globally. If you need to get the ID of the current item, your hit on this page makes sense, so what do you give and what does not make sense is on your consideration...
[Get context data at the Workflow Start form](https://community.nintex.com/thread/1285)